# Can't find how to run Cucumber step tests

Tags: eclipse, junit, cucumber

I am using for the first time Cucumber java version (using also Eclipse) and I have a problem I can't resolve.

I achieved to write my RunCukesTest class, one feature file and one java file (which corresponds to the steps given in the feature file).

The problem is that when I run with JUnit the RunCukesTest class, all my scenarios are skipped and when I click on them in the JUnit display, the error is "Test class not found in selected project".

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: can you paste your cucumberRunner Class? probably you are missing Glue or step definitions are not configured properly

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, I just forgot to delete the "throw new PendingException()" mention at the end of all my steps ... :@

Nevertheless, I have found out that in my RunCukesTest, I had to specify the package for the "glue" option and not the classpath.

Thank you for your answer.